# Resource field is not valid. You must enter a valid ARN

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to create an S3 Bucket policy using AWS Policy Generator and following the basic steps.

I copied the arn from bucket page and added /* after pasting ARN but getting the error message and add statement tab is not getting active.

[AWS Policy Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4u7S.png)

Comment: Snapshot of error is attached. Bucket ARN is copy pasted so no error there and adding /* after pasting ARN.

Answer (score 4):

Open the developer tools, and execute these lines:

```js
String.prototype.match = ()=>true
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {return "Do you want to exit this page?";}
```

After that if will never fail the ARN validation

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it with one of my buckets and got the same error.
This might be an issue with the AWS Policy Generator.

There is actually a discussion and tickets open for this on AWS re:Post:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUjnr5ei9VQm-YpIle6R4UrQ/why-my-s-3-policy-generator-dosent-work

I can suggest to you the same workaround they suggested on the link above.
you can create your policy with the wild card, just `*`, no ARN.
then in the generated JSON, just look for the line `"Resource": "*",` and replace the wild card with your actual ARN.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example at Dec 2023

```html
{
  "Id": "Policy1703586771043",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1703586768971",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<s3Bucketname>",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "<ARN_As_it is from IAM user>"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```